# Azure service bus with biztalk server 2016

Tags: biztalk, azure-servicebus-queues, biztalk-2016, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I'm looking for any feedback on using Azure service bus with Biztalk server 2016 for queuing some web requests in a high traffic group

Comment: why not using Logic Apps instead? so everything will be cloud based.

Comment: Because all my business logic and processing are already on Biztalk. So instead to expose our orchestration as web services that exceed sometimes the wait timeout from partners, I want to queue theses requests from Azure ami manager to a queue and send a technical ack on this. Biztalk will process asynchronously from the queue. The articles shared on internet are just to discover this feature but I'm looking for a real production feedback

Comment: what we did before is to use traffic manager and create a web app to send data to on premise sql server via biztalk hybrid connection manager. then a wcf polling in biztalk end to get those data from database.

Comment: My issue is to return an ack asap, some eco sites use these calls for there on-line orders. So I want to avoid any random problems network or latency to send the ack. With service bus there is no need to send the request to onpremise app or db

Comment: Is BizTalk in Azure or on-prem?

Comment: VMs are hosted in Azure

Comment: Are you having a specific problem handling the throughput with BizTalk?

Comment: We need to queue some data a inbound w b request for asynchronous processing. Some partners receive timeout when the published orchestration take a long time execution. We want also to use this service for pub-sub for new integration flows on the cloud. Do you have any experience with this service?